# CSS Blur trouble with IE 11 - workaround?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, canvas

I am writing a responsive web page using a blur filter to full screen blur an image. It is a big image and I use it as background. The point is, I use it as background as a CSS background.
E.g. I don't use

`<img src` etc.

I use the css property `background`. This gives me the advantage of using `background-size` for the responsive layouts. E.g. cutting off edges for mobile devices, and automatic shrinking, depending on landscape and portrait too.

This would be a lot of work, to do by hand.

Problem is, sadly, IE. Internet explorer 11 does not offer a way to use css blurring.

**EDIT** as mentioned in the comments, I could just blur the image myself in photoshop and am done.
 The problem is, for lower resolutions I need different blur levels. If the screen size is 600x400 I cannot use the same blur that I was using for 1920x1200. So I have to blur ALL background images I have for ALL resolutions I am using. Then implement a loading Technic to only load the images that are needed. There are many background images. Around 50 total. New ones should be able to be added by the customer as well. I really don't see me making him do this process.

I read about:

[StackBlur](https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur)

But I can't seem to get it working.

[What I tried in a codepen so far](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myqbXG)

HTML

```
<canvas id="canv" ></canvas>
```

CSS

```
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
            border: 10px #c0272b outset;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 2px #333;
            cursor: default !important;
  background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,...') center center no-repeat;
        }
```

JS

```
 stackBlurCanvasRGB( "canv", 0, 0, 100, 100, 5 );
```

[as a reference the codepen i stole the image from](http://codepen.io/jaschahal/pen/favmd)

Comment: I know that Stack Overflow requires you to include your code within the question, but you **really** didn't need to include an entire 24 kB data URI with it...

Comment: Can't you just blur the image and use the blurred one as the background?

Comment: Stackblur does work, so give it another try :-)

Comment: @markE it works for plain images. It is though, not working for background elements as we know it.

Comment: You can (1) pull the background image into a JS image object, (2) blur that image object and (3) reapply it as a background image. But I'm worried I don't understand your use-cases. It's trivial to do a one-time blur of 50+ images times 3 or 4 media sizes and serve them with media queries.

Comment: @markE I thought about doing that too, but really, it sounds crap doesnt it? Like trying to eat a steak with a spoon. It might lead to many problems in performance too. The use case? The user is too dumb to do blurring himself when adding new pages. I think I will switch to blurring the images server side when he uploads one.

Comment: That's what I would do--blur your current images and have the customer upload new images to a staging directory to also be blurred. :-)